# Bringing in single and multi-line App log records to ELK (some contain JSON objects)

Tags: logging, logstash, kibana

I'm trying to take log records from a custom (node.js) application that will be putting data into elastic search and then processed by Kibana. My environment is Ubuntu with ELK (Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana) and the log generating Application is in Node.JS

I'm already processing the standard system log files, like syslog, nginx. The ELK environment and the Apps are on different servers

Since this is a log file that is created by our App it contains entries that have various patterns. But each entry does start with a common header 
[example - *2015-03-17T11:26:27.285Z (INFO|dev3)* ) Creating interaction document...] 
which is 
[*date+time stamp (msg-level|system-ID) Some message text* ]

Frequently this is the entire log entry. But sometimes it can be followed by a JSON object. Depending on the message being generated it may have a different JSON Object. If a JSON object is included(starting on the next line) the line will end with "..." (minus the quotes) but not all lines that end that way have a JSON object following.

As a first step I'd line to bring in the entire multi-line JSON object as part of the message. Right now I'm using the syslog filter and each line comes in as a separate message. Then my ultimate goal would be to parse the JSON objects and have the contained fields stored separately so that Kibana can cleanly filter on their individual values.

From what I've seen so far there are two ways this can be done.

- Create logstash filters to parse and then pass to Elasticesearch
- Have the Application write the information directly to the elasticsearch database. Maybe with something like log4j.

My first question is which method would be the most flexible in the long run ? Creating a multi-line filter and importing the JSON object as a single message is probably the quickest. But if writing directly to elastic search makes it easier to bring in different JSON objects and have the individual fields available to the filters that would probably be my longer term goal.

I am including some dummy sample log data below to show what I am looking to process

Thanks

```
2015-03-17T11:26:27.285Z (INFO|dev3) Creating interaction document...
{ req_url: '/nL4sWsw',
  company_cookie: '68d1dc4a32ed3bfd22c96a6e60a132924e5d8fa8',
  browsing_cookie: '68d1dc4a32ed3bfd22c96a6e60a132924e5d8fa8',
  visit_count: 1,
  campaign_id: 52d6ab20bbc1e6ac0500032f,
  switchboard_id: 54888c6ffc4ac2cb18a3b8c6,
  content_key: '2d0515120561b7be80c936027f6dce71b41a0391',
  http_header: 
   { 'x-host': 'subdomain.company.org',
     'x-ip': '111.222.333.444',
     host: 'logic9',
     connection: 'close',
     'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; ext-monitor - premium monitoring service; http://www.ext-monitor.com)' },
  timestamp: Tue Mar 17 2015 06:26:27 GMT-0500 (CDT),
  url: 'https://cdn.company.org/2d0515120561b7be80c936027f6dce71b41a0391/',
  type7id: 'nL4sWsw',
  pid: undefined,
  onramp_type: 'type7',
  http_user_agent: 'Other',
  http_browser: 'Other' }
2015-03-17T11:26:27.285Z (INFO|dev3) Inserting interactions data...
{ 'statistics.total_interactions': 1,
  'statistics.day_of_week.tuesday': 1,
  'statistics.onramp_type.type7': 1,
  'statistics.hour_of_day.11': 1,
  'statistics.operating_systems.other': 1,
  'statistics.browser_types.other': 1 }
2015-03-17T11:26:27.286Z (INFO|dev3) Updating campaign 52d6ab20bbc1e6ac0500032f with stats {"statistics.total_interactions":1,"statistics.day_of_week.tuesday":1,"statistics.onramp_type.type7":1,"statistics.hour_of_day.11":1,"statistics.operating_systems.other":1,"statistics.browser_types.other":1} ...
2015-03-17T11:26:27.286Z (INFO|dev3) Redirecting to https://cdn.company.org/2d0515120561b7be80c936027f6dce71b41a0391/ ...
2015-03-17T11:26:27.286Z (INFO|dev3) Campaign statistics recorded successfully
2015-03-17T11:26:27.287Z (INFO|dev3) GET /zVoxiPV
2015-03-17T11:26:27.287Z (INFO|dev3) GET /vumkm3A
2015-03-17T11:26:27.287Z (INFO|dev3) Starting response for type7v1 ...
2015-03-17T11:26:27.287Z (INFO|dev3) Header: {"x-host":"subdomain.company.org","x-ip":"111.222.333.444","host":"logic9","connection":"close","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; ext-monitor - premium monitoring service; http://www.ext-monitor.com)"}
2015-03-17T11:26:27.287Z (INFO|dev3) Params: {"tid":"zVoxiPV"}
2015-03-17T11:26:27.287Z (INFO|dev3) Sending taIdentity cookie: f79b8ceca66f99608fb1291ab51d65b08fa3138f ...
2015-03-17T11:26:27.287Z (INFO|dev3) Sending taBrowse cookie: f79b8ceca66f99608fb1291ab51d65b08fa3138f ...
2015-03-17T11:26:27.287Z (INFO|dev3) Sending new cookie: 96ec5414d0b847790f58a1feee2399d282cf7907 with visit count 1 ...
2015-03-17T11:26:27.288Z (INFO|dev3) Finding in switchboard {"active":true,"campaign.start_at":{"$lte":"2015-03-17T11:26:27.287Z"},"campaign.end_at":{"$gte":"2015-03-17T11:26:27.287Z"},"type7id":"zVoxiPV"}
2015-03-17T11:26:27.288Z (INFO|dev3) Starting response for type7v1 ...
2015-03-17T11:26:27.288Z (INFO|dev3) Header: {"x-host":"subdomain.company.org","x-ip":"111.222.333.444","host":"logic9","connection":"close","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; ext-monitor - premium monitoring service; http://www.ext-monitor.com)"}
2015-03-17T11:26:27.288Z (INFO|dev3) Params: {"tid":"vumkm3A"}
2015-03-17T11:26:27.288Z (INFO|dev3) Sending taIdentity cookie: adec72a656ef7999d101edc7e1e9cf901e1e56c9 ...
2015-03-17T11:26:27.288Z (INFO|dev3) Sending taBrowse cookie: adec72a656ef7999d101edc7e1e9cf901e1e56c9 ...
2015-03-17T11:26:27.288Z (INFO|dev3) Sending new cookie: 0c1354b30bf261595bf24a14c2e90ecac64545ed with visit count 1 ...
2015-03-17T11:26:27.288Z (INFO|dev3) Finding in switchboard {"active":true,"campaign.start_at":{"$lte":"2015-03-17T11:26:27.288Z"},"campaign.end_at":{"$gte":"2015-03-17T11:26:27.288Z"},"type7id":"vumkm3A"}
2015-03-17T11:26:27.289Z (INFO|dev3) Finding in matching set [object Object]
2015-03-17T11:26:27.289Z (INFO|dev3) Switchboard item {"_id":"5488a7ea60c5508693bebba7","content_provider":"redirect","content":{"_id":"54b8954eca0ca5eb87cb4fef","name":"Content for Switchboard 5488a7ea60c5508693bebba7","key":"ad354806eadd0f90ef55b1ab96a8c84272401186"},"type":"redirect","campaign":{"end_at":"2018-12-11T00:00:00.000Z","start_at":"2008-12-11T00:00:00.000Z","_id":"52a9dd9bfb9c94150600032f"}}
2015-03-17T11:26:27.289Z (INFO|dev3) No url for redirect, going local...
2015-03-17T11:26:27.289Z (INFO|dev3) url: https://cdn.company.org/ad354806eadd0f90ef55b1ab96a8c84272401186/
2015-03-17T11:26:27.289Z (INFO|dev3) Sending redirect to https://cdn.company.org/ad354806eadd0f90ef55b1ab96a8c84272401186/ ...
2015-03-17T11:26:27.289Z (INFO|dev3) Creating interaction document...
{ req_url: '/zVoxiPV',
  company_cookie: 'f79b8ceca66f99608fb1291ab51d65b08fa3138f',
  browsing_cookie: 'f79b8ceca66f99608fb1291ab51d65b08fa3138f',
  visit_count: 1,
  campaign_id: 52a9dd9bfb9c94150600032f,
  switchboard_id: 5488a7ea60c5508693bebba7,
  content_key: 'ad354806eadd0f90ef55b1ab96a8c84272401186',
  http_header: 
   { 'x-host': 'subdomain.company.org',
     'x-ip': '111.222.333.444',
     host: 'logic9',
     connection: 'close',
     'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; ext-monitor - premium monitoring service; http://www.ext-monitor.com)' },
  timestamp: Tue Mar 17 2015 06:26:27 GMT-0500 (CDT),
  url: 'https://cdn.company.org/ad354806eadd0f90ef55b1ab96a8c84272401186/',
  type7id: 'zVoxiPV',
  pid: undefined,
  onramp_type: 'type7',
  http_user_agent: 'Other',
  http_browser: 'Other' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about crating an application to write logs to elasticsearch, you're just reinventing the wheel. Logstash can do this, you just need to do a bit of reading in to how to get it to do what you want it to do. When you pass a json encoded message to the json filter in logstash it will take the key value pairs and once sent to elasticsearch that data will be indexed and searchable.

I would suggest you just need to do a few things first, put in a [mulitline](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/multiline) filter to get the json encoded data on to the same line. I have only ever used the multiline filter to rejoin lines which have a one identifying feature that you can use to match off at the start/end of the line. In your case I cannot see one, but I think you can chain 2 multiline filters together instead:

```
filter {
  multiline {
    #this one will look for any line starting with whitespace and join it to the previous line
    what => "previous"
    pattern  => "^\s"
  }
  multiline {
    #this one will look for any line starting with { and join it to the previous line
    what => "previous"
    pattern  => "^\{"
  }
}
```

After the multiline filter I would use a [grok](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/grok) filter, this can be used to pull out the date and any other parts of the message, you should be able to use this to capture the json encoded part of the message and then, you can run that through the [json](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/json) filter one you have it captured to a field.

Comment: I wasn't planning on writing a custom program to do this. I was mentioning that these log records come from a custom App and therefore probably wouldn't have a specific filter already existing. I have been doing more digging and realized that Winston(we use Winston to create these log records) may already have a transport option that could write directly to the elasticsearch DB. The basic log records are no problem, but the JSON object is not all a single level and may be a bit more involved to parse. But I can start with just getting it all in one message instead of chopped up line by line

Comment: Sorry, just noticed that the formatting didn't get applied to my post. It should be easier to understand the filters I was trying to explain now... That filter should be useful trying to get the logs on to a single line.

Comment: Thanks @Rumbles . I had to make an update to your example. I didn't catch it at first but the " =>" was missing in the pattern line. That was enough to get me started. The JSON object now shows up in the single message :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have a lot of experience with logstash and the multi-line filter and I can tell you that it's very fragile and very difficult to debug when things go wrong.

logstash can ingest json without any problem if you remove all the newlines and make sure it's a proper json. So my recommendation would be to make sure the application is writing the json in a way that will be easily ingested with logstash especially if this is a custom application.